# Why is my map stamp particle effect not visible?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Yesterday I bought a map stamp for the map CP_Steel, but when I visited that map I didn't see any special hat effect.

Comment: Thought the more stamps you bought for the map the stronger your particle effect is.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure the effect is visible if you stand still or if you taunt. You have probably to move to see the particle effect of World's Traveler hat.

Try to play on CP_Steel on a server with replay available, save one replay and verify if the particle for your hat is visible. As soon as I arrive home I will try and confirm that.

Comment: May 8th- "as soon as I arrive home I will try and confrim that". It certainly has taken a while for you to get home :)

Answer (score 0):

You can hardly see the unusual effect, as Valve would not give you a normal unusual for 69p. Try moving around and looking very closely. They are tiny white bits coming out of the front of the hat. Also, you need to be on CP_Steel for the unusual effect to show.